# Specify distance from page margin to header with geometry

Tags: spacing, header-footer, margins, geometry

With `geometry`, the placement of the header is set by specifying the distance from the text body below to the header above with `headsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, headsep = 5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{A header plus the page number: \thepage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

In MS Word, on the other hand, the placement of the header is set by specifying the distance from the page margin above to the header below:

[image]

My problem now is that I am given a guide that tells me the settings in MS Word, and I have to figure out how to translate that into LaTeX. And this setting I can't figure out. How can I with the help of `geometry` set the distance from the page margin above to the header below (in which case I would just set `headsep = 0pt`)?

Comment: Then you first have to explain what Word mean. What do they mean by header from to? Measured from where to where? Top of text to top of page? Baseline of header to top of page?

Comment: One way of doing this is to get a hold of a PDF generated from word that meet the criteria, then put it in the background of a latex doc that has the same page dims, then start fidling. That is what I usually do when replicating Office generated stuff in LaTeX

Comment: @daleif When I set the measure to `0`, the text didn't extend beyond the paper margin, so it seems like `Header from Top` sets the distance from the page top margin to the _top_ of the character boxes inside the header (not to imply that Word uses "boxes", of course).

Comment: In geometry you can set the headheight of the header box. So via topmargin, headheight, and headsep you can set what is needed to get x above the header box

Comment: @daleif That's exactly what I thought, too. So I tried - and failed ... `:-/`

Comment: then post what failed.

Comment: @daleif I think I just had a eureka moment ...

Comment: @daleif Right, so the distance from the top margin to the top of the header is `tmargin - headheight - headsep`. So knowing `tmargin`, I just need to make `headheight` big enough to contain my text, and then set `headsep` to whatever vertical size is left after doing `tmargin - distance from margin to header - headheight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I how I ended up doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
    tmargin = 24mm,% distance from page margin to body text
    headheight = 4.22mm,% height of header (the minimum required by fancyhdr)
    % tmargin (24mm) - headsep (X mm) - headheight (4.22mm) = 16mm (= the desired distance from page margin to header) =
    headsep = 3.78mm,% distance from body text to header    
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{A header plus the page number: \thepage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should specify `top` together with the `includehead` setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,includehead,top=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{A header plus the page number: \thepage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

From the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) [user's manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf), Figure 2 displays the meaning of `includehead` (and `includefoot`):

[image]

If you now want to specify the distance from the top of the page (margin) to the top of the text body, additionally set `headsep` and `headheight`. For example, we can set `headheight` to `\baselineskip` by default, and then set

```
\geometry{
  showframe,
  includehead,
  top=5mm,
  headsep=\dimexpr20mm-\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip
}
```

to have the top of the body text exactly `25mm` from the page top margin.

Comment: This sets the distance from the page margin to the header, but now how do I control the distance from the page margin to the body text?

Comment: @Sverre: That wasn't part of your original question, was it?

Comment: True - it wasn't.

Comment: @Sverre: I've added some reference to set the other length as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if using `\baselineskip` is a good idea. If `fancyhdr` thinks that a value greater than `\baselineskip` is needed for `headheight`, it will simply overwrite your specification and set its own height. And if so, the distances between text and margins will not be what the `geometry` code would lead you to think it will be. I think it's best to look and see if `fancyhdr` complains or not, and if it does, then set `headheight` to whatever `fancyhdr` asks for.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the correct values manually since you’ll hav to set them only once, don’t you? If the values are changing quite often you can use this code

```
\makeatletter
\geometry{
   showframe,
   top=20mm,
   headsep = \dimexpr\Gm@tmargin-\headheight-5mm\relax,
}
\makeatother
```

Where `\makeatletter` enables `@` as part of command names. Then in `\dimexpr` (*dimension expression* terminated by `\relax`) we us the top margin, which must be set *before* `headsep` width `top` (!), and subtract the `\headheight` and an additional 5mm. Resulting in the header starting 5mm from the top of the page.

Comment: And where does gm@tmargin come from? Might not be a good idea to expose internal macros for user use as the internals might change in the future

Comment: @daleif: It’s an internal macro of `geometry`. And of course it’s not a good idea to use internal macros but using `\topmargin` didn’t work …