# Accuracy of distance measures in geometry

Tags: margins, geometry, lengths

In the following MWE, I set the distance from the edge of the paper to the body text to be 25mm.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paper = a4paper, tmargin = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Yet both when I inspect the paper at full size in a pdf viewer like Evince and when I print the paper, I get 27mm when I measure with a ruler. Why? Is `geometry` inaccurate?

Comment: How exactly are you measuring?

Comment: @daleif The distance from the edge of the paper to the rule set by `showframe`.

Comment: There is some consistency here. When I follow [this procedure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264246/9077) to give me 16mm from the paper edge to the top rule of the header, I measure 18mm with a ruler. So the paper edge always seems to be 2mm further away from the header and body text than expected.

Comment: Measured how, on screen, print, where exactly does tmargin go? Edge of paper to edge of text box? Note that printing is often hit by a scaling artifact in the PDF previewer.

Comment: Is your printer setting put to "Fit to margins", thereby shrinking the page?

Comment: @daleif As mentioned in my question, I measure _both_ on screen and in print, and I measure with a ruler. And when I print, I print with the document's actual size, with no scaling. In both cases, it's 2mm more. `tmargin` goes from the paper edge to the edge of text box (I use `showframe` and I measure up to the rules given).

Comment: @Werner Nope, I print from Adobe Reader with the setting "Actual size".

Comment: You're measuring the wrong thing. The distance from the edge of the paper to the first *baseline* is exactly 25mm plus `\topskip` (unless the first line is unusually high).

Comment: @egreg But I was measuring the exact same distance that Ulrike's tikz arrow says is 25mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tikz claims it is 25mm:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paper = a4paper, tmargin = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[<->,red] (current page.north) --++(0,-25mm)node[midway]{25mm};
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Could you please elaborate? Are you drawing an arrow that's 25mm long, and then you visually see that the arrow heads touch the edges?

Comment: He he, that was what I was just going to do,

Comment: Yes. You naturally have to trust the length calculations of tikz (I do).

Comment: So - you're drawing a 25mm arrow that starts from the paper edge, right, and then you see where it ends up? (In this case at the `showframe` rule)

Comment: @daleif: I have a lot of training with such arrows. I'm placing them everywhere to check distances ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, same here. When ever I'm tasked to replicate some existing design, I start by overlaying an existing PDF of the target design with various guidelines. It is a very useful tool. In the past I just did it with `eso-pic`, `tikz` is just easier.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. The first line of your output is 6.94444pt high (TeX told me so, it's the largest height of the characters in the line, which is ‘d’), which is preceded by glue deriving from `\topskip` in the amount of 3.05556pt, because

> 6.94444 + 3.05556 = 10

and 10pt is the standard value of `\topskip` for a ten point size document.

The distance from the paper edge to the first baseline is 25mm plus `\topskip`. Since 3.05556pt = 1.074mm, the distance from the paper edge to the top of the ‘d’ is 26.074mm.

On the other hand, if you measure the top of the opening ‘L’, which is just 6.83331pt, you have to add 0.11113pt = 0.039mm and you get 26.113mm.

If you measure from the top of ‘o’, which is 4.30554pt=1.513mm high, you get

> 25 + 1.074 + 1.513 = 27.587

millimeters.

So it's just a matter of deciding how you do the measurement.

If you set `\topskip=0pt`, say after `\begin{document}` in Ulrike's code, you get

[image]

so indeed the distance is measured from the paper edge to the top of the highest character on the line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paper = a4paper, tmargin = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt

\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[<->,red] (current page.north) 
  --++(0,-25mm)node[midway]{25mm};
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Of course, changing TeX's model just to comply with silly specifications is wrong, but sometimes needed.

Why does TeX use `\topskip`? Because in this way the position of the first baseline on the page will not depend on the line's contents (unless it's unusually large in height), which is not guaranteed if `\topskip` is set to zero.

Comment: I understand, but you seem to be assuming here that I got 27mm by measuring from the paper edge to some character in the first line of the body text. I didn't. I measured from the paper edge to the rule given by `showframe`, which, as I understand you, includes `\topskip`. I can't explain why I get 27mm when measuring with a ruler when `tikz` says it's 25mm, but I do ...

Comment: @Sverre Check your printer and the print settings: sometimes printer drivers assume that A4 paper doesn't fit on A4 paper (the one of Adobe Reader used to). I'll remove the answer if you think it doesn't help.

Comment: i checked all the settings I could find. But I'm actually very pleased that you guys are showing me that `geometry` gets it right. If the editor or the publisher complains, then I know I'm in the right (I was given permission to typeset my contribution for a book after I witnessed the horror of the first proofs handed to me a few days ago).

Comment: @Sverre: Measures on a print out are never accurate. Paper in a printer can move a bit. Print the example with the arrow  (you can add some more, or rulers to get a better impression).

Comment: @Sverre Try measuring the text width and height, that should be 147mm and 236.4mm respectively. If you find 135.2mm and 217.5mm, then you know that your printer scales down the PDF at 92%.

Comment: 147mm+ and 237mm is what I get. Seems to be a paper margin thing that I get 2mm off there.